# Not interpolating contourf function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to represent a two variable function on Matlab that takes values {-1,1} and I am using the prebuilt function `contourf` since it's the only one I know to represent filled 2D plots. It is a simple function (sort of a checkerboard ina cartesian mesh) and I want the color of each cell to be determined by the value of the function on the bottom left vertex. The problem is that, for each square cell, this function it is always interpolating the value on each vertex. Is there an straightforward way to fix this?

I leave my code here as an example.

```
n = 3; % mesh size
L = 2^n;
x = linspace(0,1,2^n+1);
f = ones(L+1);
for j=1:L/2
    f(:,j) = -1; 
end
% this generates a basic checkerboard consisting of two stripes: one black and one white
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x);
contourf(X,Y,f,'linecolor','none');
set(gca,'Yticklabel',[]) 
set(gca,'Xticklabel',[])
set(gca,'XColor','none','YColor','none','TickDir','out')

black = [0 0 0];
white = [1 1 1];
colormap(gca,[black; white]) % binary colormap
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is not completely clear what your expected output is. Can you add images with the current output and why it is not as you expect? Also, what do you call "a cell"? It already means something in MATLAB

Comment: If what you want is to have more control on a filled 2D plot, you can use MATLAB's `fill` function

Comment: @BillBokeey if instead of n=3 we set n=1 in the code, the mesh would consist just of 4 cells (squares) arranged as a 2x2 checkerboard. I would like to define a function f (with binary values) on the vertices of those squares and asign a color (black or white) to each square depending on the value of the function on the bottom left corner of the square.

Comment: @BillBokeey As the code is right now but with n=1, if I define f({0,0}) = f({0,1}) = black and f({1,0}) = f({1,1}) = white, for the first vertical stripe that I want black, I would get an interpolation of the values between f({0,:}) and f({1,:}). That is, a scale of grays if I set colormap(gray), or just a change of color in x=1/2 with the binary scale of color that I define on the code.

Comment: "if instead of n=3 we set n=1 in the code, the mesh would consist just of 4 cells (squares) arranged as a 2x2 checkerboard" No, it doesn´t. Nothing in your code creates square patches of numbers, just strips. Have you had a look at `fill`?

Comment: @BillBokeey I meant that the mesh can be seen as a 2^n x 2^n patch, before inserting any colors. Then of course the values I assign to the function that I define on the mesh create stripes. I had a look at ```fill```, but I would like to manipulate the function after this initial definition and ```fill``` doesn't seem to fit. I'll keep trying though, thanks a lot!